# Objective-C: Words to NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to convert words into number like `Ninety Nine to 99` `Second to 2nd` and `Two to 2`  etc

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: This question has already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299619/algorithm-that-converts-numeric-amount-into-english-words

Comment: @FawazTahir, It is not the same. That is a different question and has nothing to do with objective c. Here the question is to convert from words to numbers. Not the reverse.

Comment: My apologies. I misread that.

Comment: yup correct ACB, I searched alot before asking the question.

Comment: @iArezki, You are making the same mistake as I did earlier. It is not from number to word.

Comment: Questions:  Is this for, eg, "compressing" written text, or for providing a "natural language" interface?  Will the writers be fairly formal, or "casual" in their writing.  Does the translation need to be 100% accurate, 98%, 90%?  Can the tool "throw up its hands" on some sequences (and perhaps ask for assistance), or must it translate everything?

Comment: (And will you be dealing with dollars and cents in some cases?  Distinguishing "fifteen-ninetynine == 1599 from "fifteen-ninetynine" = $15.99 is a definite challenge.)

Comment: (And consider that "five hundred forty two" = 542, but "ten twenty" = $10.20 or 10:20.)

Comment: (I think it's doable, to a "non banker" level of precision.  But it's more than a couple hours of work.)

Comment: This seems like a terrible issue to have to address! Mainly because of all the various combinations, misspellings, etc as @Hot Licks eludes to...! Is this existing data or parsing from data input? If existing data... well, good luck!... else, can't you just limit the input character set on a field, instead? (say, to number characters, only)?

Answer (score 6):

There is no API from Apple for this kind of purpose. Lexicographical analysis is hard even if it is just for a single language. Expressing a number as words might be relatively simple, but getting from words to numbers would require dealing with many special cases.

The brute force approach would be to have a database of all the various possible combinations.  A smarter approach would probably analyse the individual words and reason what number that could mean.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You are looking for this, [NSNumberFormatterStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSNumberFormatterStyle). It has an option as `NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle`.</strike>

As per the apple  documentation,

> **NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle:** Specifies a spell-out format; for example, “23” becomes “twenty-three”.

Looks like you want to **convert from Word to Number and not Number to Word**. I misread your question.

You might have to manually do that as there are no APIs available from Apple for that. You can check [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and see if you can find something helpful for this.

As jlehr mentioned, `NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"one hundred forty-three"]);` will give the number `143`. But it may not be a perfect solution which works with all possible combinations.

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter` will at least get you part of the way there. For example `NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"one hundred forty-three"]);` correctly yields the number **143**, given a formatter instance set to use the `NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle`.

Comment: @jlehr, Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't sure that will work with all possible combinations.

Comment: yup really nice comment jlehr