# Having issue in converting int 1 to string 'one', 2 to 'two' etc in java

Tags: java, string, int

I have to convert int 1 to string 'one', 2 to 'two' etc in java, could any one please explain me how to do that in Java. Is it possible?

Comment: Make a method containg swtich and return the desired string accordingly.

Comment: No, it is not possible (sarcasm).

Comment: There is already similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299619/algorithm-that-converts-numeric-amount-into-english-words

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Starting with zero, the bottom twenty-one numbers have individual names, then there are patterns up to hundred, thousand, million, and so on.

Comment: To add onto this, special case 0. From there, include a negative if necessary. Split the digits into groups of three and use special cases to build those. Then use log10s to figure out what radix the digit is at, apply the proper end (thousand, million, billion).
For example: 127233. -> One hundred twenty-seven thousand, two hundred thirty-three.

Comment: @Legend good point. Edited.  I'd +1 your comment, but for some reason, I haven't been able to do that lately from this browser... or acknowledge that I've viewed comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] strArr = {"zero","one","two"};

String one = strArr [1];
```

Comment: 2 billion elements later...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but there's no magical way of getting it working so you have to code it all manually.

One way is to simply write an switch/case clause returning the converted value, as such:

```
public static String convertNumber(int i) {
    switch(i) {
        case 1: 
            return "one";
        case 2:
            return "two";
       } //etc
}
```

Another is to add them all to a map and use that, as such:

```
Map<Integer, String> numbersMap = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
numbersMap.add(1, "one");
numbersMap.add(2, "two"); //etc
```

and then use the following to get the desired String:

```
numbersMap.get(int);
```

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3911982/1690982) for a general solution to "all" numbers.

Comment: If you are using `return` then `break` doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @Smit Thank you - my auto-type mode apparently kicked in..

Comment: I can use Switch or Map, but I was trying for any generic method which converts numeric number to word format because I might have to display number in hundred's. Thank you.

Comment: @user442928 see the link I posted at the bottom of the post.